# Piecewise linear regression with Keras

Tags: python, keras, linear-regression, piecewise

Is there a way to do piecewise linear regression with Keras, or alternatively achieve similar performance? I have multivariate data with a single regression target per sample, but the data can be split into N distinct segments, each of which exhibit behavior different from the other segments. I assume that one way to achieve piecewise linear regression would be to have a separate output layer per segment, but I don't know how to do that without making a multi-input and multi-output model, which in this particular case isn't an ideal approach.

Comment: do you mean 1-d input to 1-d output?  a relu unit is the knot point of a piecewise linear regression, so you just need one for each segment ( but perhaps more to search the space)

Comment: I mean N-d input to 1-d output. Could you please elaborate more on the second sentence, I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean. Thanks.

Comment: the way you do piecewise linear regression normally, is just add inputs of form max(x-x_i, 0) to normal linear regression. (in 1-d case).  you would do product of these terms for multidimensional case.

Comment: see https://newonlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/node/310/

Comment: I'm not sure that really answers my question because I don't have problems with the theory of piecewise regression but rather with its application using Keras.

Comment: could you put in your question an example formula you want to construct in keras

Comment: I don't have any specific formula as such, just a general multivariate case of piecewise regression. A Keras application of univariate piecewise regression would be useful too in this case because it'd provide me with a starting point, but I have not come across one.